# PHP Regex question

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse some text for example:

```
$text = "Blah blah [a]findme[/a] and [b]findmetoo[b], maybe also [z]me[/z].";
```

What I have now is:

```
preg_match_all("/[*?](.*?)[\/*?]/", $text, $matches);
```

Which doesn't work unfortunately.

Any ideas how to parse, return the node key and the corresponding node value?

Comment: What values can the `key` contain, and can the `value` contain keys/values?

Comment: i think you wanted to put `$text = "Blah blah [a]findme[/a] and [b]findmetoo[/b], maybe also [z]me[/z]."; instead of
`$text = "Blah blah [a]findme[/a] and [b]findmetoo[b], maybe also [z]me[/z].";
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well firstly by you not putting `()` around your `*?` your not matching the tag name, and secondly, using `[*?]` will match multiple `[` until the `]` where you want to match inside, so you should be doing `[(.*?)]` and `[\/(.*?)]`

You would have to try something along the lines of:

```
/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/(.*?)\]/is
```

this is not guaranteed to work but will get you closer.

you could also do:

```
/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/is
```

and then foreach result loop recursively until preg_match_all returns false, that's a possible way how to do nesting.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match the same tags, you need a backreference:

This assumes no nesting, if you need nesting then let me know.

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('#\[([^\]]+)\](.+?)\[/\1\]#', $text, $matches)) {
   // $matches[0] - entire matched section
   // $matches[1] - keys
   // $matches[2] - values
}
```

Incidentally, I do not know what you are going to do with this bbcode style work, but usually you would want to use [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to deal with inline modification of this sort of text, with a regexp similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$pattern = "/\[a\](.*?)\[\/a\]/";
$text = "Blah blah [a]findme[/a] and [b]findmetoo[b], maybe also [z]me[/z].";
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/?.*?\]/", $text, $matches);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/aAgTV)

Changes made:

- `[` and `]` are regex meta-characters
  used to define character class. To
  match literal `[` and `]` you need to
  escape them.
- To match any arbitrary text(without
  newline) in non-greedy way you use
  `.*?`.
- To match the node key you need to
  enclose the pattern matching it in
  `(..)` so that they get captured.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this regex `((\[[^\/]\]).+?(\[\/[^\/]\]))`. Hope will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex monkey, but I think you need to escape those brackets and create groups to search for, as brackets don't return results (parentheses do):

```
preg_match_all("/\\[(*?)\\](.*?)\\[\(\/*?)\\]/", $text, $matches);
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Should your second example also be captured even though the [b] "tag" is not closed with the [\b] backslash 'b'. If tags should be properly closed then use

```
/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/\1\]/
```

This will ensure that opening and closing tags match.